# Can I copy a file from one instance of vifm to another?

Tags: vifm

I have multiple launched instances of `vifm`. Is it possible to copy a file from one instance to another (using `yy`)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**BEFORE v0.10**

No, you can't do this easily. Instances don't share their run-time state (content of registers in this case), so when you <kbd>yy</kbd> file in one of them, other instances are not aware of it.

As a workaround for the cases when you really want this:

1. (in dst instance) Run `:write` to save current state into `vifminfo` file.
2. (in src instance) Do <kbd>yy</kbd> and then `:write`, which will *merge* states of two instances.
3. (in dst instance) Run `:restart` to reload state (this can bring more than just registers) and do <kbd>p</kbd>.

It's not really something I'd recommend, but it should work and might be acceptable in some cases.

**SINCE v0.10**

Now there is [`'syncregs'`](https://vifm.info/vimdoc.shtml#vifm-%27syncregs%27) option, which enables one to share registers among instances. Here's its description:

> Specifies identifier of group of instances that share registers between each
>   other.  When several instances of vifm have this option set to identical
>   value, they automatically synchronize contents of their registers on
>   operations which use them.

So, putting this to your `vifmrc` should be enough:

```
set syncregs=general
```

Or just set the option temporarily when you need the sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Define a map to save current file:

```
nmap Wf :!ls -1 %f | while read f ; do printf ":!cp %%s/%%s %%s\n" %d $f '%%d' ; done > ~/.vifm_tmp <cr>
```

And a second mapping that will source the temporary file:

```
nmap Pf :source ~/.vifm_tmp<cr>
```

To copy the file: `Wf` in the first vifm instance then `Pf` in the second instance. This works with multiple selected (tagged) files but does not work in visual mode.

You can also sync the source directory:

```
nmap Yd :!printf ":cd %%s\n" %d > ~/.vifm_tmp<cr> 
nmap Pd :source ~/.vifm_tmp <cr>
```

then copy/paste between the panels of the same instance.

Comment: That's an interesting approach. However, there is already a builtin functionality for sharing registers since v0.10, look at my updated answer.